# Perspective and Balance with Multiple Characters

Tags: style, fiction, book, perspective

I am working on a piece of fiction and am having some difficulty locking down which perspective/s to utilize.  The main issue at hand is that I have 4 characters that will play "lead" roles and different intervals once they are introduced eventually becoming part of a team.

I am far from a professional when it comes to writing and am having trouble maintaining consistent perspective when writing.  There are points where the character is speaking and narrating and other points where I flip to a 3rd person story.

What I am looking for is examples of first  or third person perspective writing that tell a story from multiple character perspectives by chapter (limited 3rd person is the direction I am leaning).

The concern I have with a first person, or limited third person perspective, even thought I would prefer to tell the story from a non-omniscient view, is I am introducing a new universe/world etc and I want to demonstrate involvement in a broader social/political conflict that is brewing and I am not sure how to do this without utilizing an obvious mechanism or device that I feel can detract from storytelling.  Any suggestions for balancing the two?

Thanks for the examples and advice.

Answer (score 3):

George R.R. Martin's *A Song of Ice and Fire,* aka *Game of Thrones*, is the biggest current example. Three dozen? perspectives and counting. Introduces a new world with a huge political social conflict. Pretty much the textbook for what you're doing.

Comment: I have read the books and I have no idea why that didn't come to mind...wow...I agree with you when you say BIGGEST.  Do any other options that are perhaps less...expansive?  A pared down version of the style...its hard to absorb Martin at times, especially when it comes to continuity...if it takes 200 pages to get back to a character I completely lose track of what was happening to them earlier...

Comment: Which incidentally having taken a look at book two last night makes it somewhat difficult to emulate his style...